# DevOps Features linked (or Related) across Epics

Tags: azure-devops, devops, backlog, epic

Is it possible to have Features linked (or Related) across Epics in DevOps, whereby it is possible to view the same Feature under multiple Epics in the **Backlogs** view?

For example:

**+ EPIC: File Upload - Framework**

- FEATURE: 1 Ability upload XML Files
- FEATURE: 2 Ability upload XSLT Files
- FEATURE: 3 Ability upload TXT Files

**+ EPIC: File Upload - Client Policy**

- FEATURE: 2 Ability upload XSLT Files  **(RELATED)**
- FEATURE: 4 Filename must contain yyyy
- FEATURE: 5 xxxxxx xxxx xxxx

At present the Backlog screen only shows the parent-child relationship (i.e. Epic > Features > User Stories > Tasks). It would be nice if it could show related features.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like you're thinking, because the backlog uses hierarchy links, which are parent-child, enforcing each work item to have, at maximum, a single parent. More information under[Backlogs, portfolios, and Agile project management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops).

You could (kind of) get the functionality you want by adding dependency links (predecessor-successor) to all your work items. This allows you to link as many work items as you want as long as there is no cycle, so you could have one feature hooked up to multiple epics. But this is only possible in the Queries view, viewing a Work-Item-and-Direct-Links query, and not in the Backlog, so you would not be able to use the Backlog features at all.

What I recommend is simply to copy (duplicate) the Feature work item that you want represented under multiple Epics.